# How to Insert Value to Joomla 2.5 DB with Custom Plugin

Tags: database, plugins, joomla, insert, components

I am trying to create a joomla plugin which will insert a value into a database table for a Joomla component.  I have successfully built and installed the plugin through the Joomla Extension Manager, but when I enable the plugin, I am not seeing the value inserted in the database table.  Here is my `php` code from the plugin to review:

```
<?php
######################################################################
# Outkast Plugin                                                     #
######################################################################

// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

jimport( 'joomla.plugin.plugin');
jimport( 'joomla.html.parameter');

class plgSystemOutkastplugin extends JPlugin
{
function plgSystemOutkastplugin()
{

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$name = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/PWgvGjAhvIw?rel=0";

$columns = array('title', 'link_youtube');
$name = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/PWgvGjAhvIw?rel=0";    
$values = array($db->quote('Outkast'), $db->quote($name));

$query->insert($db->quoteName('#__mycomponent_outkastvideos'))
  ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
  ->values(implode(',', $values));

$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();

return true;

}        

}
?>
```

---

Edit Update 11/07/13:
I am adding the `xml` file from the plugin to help give some more context to the question.  Ultimately I have the combo of the php file above and the xml below to create the entire plugin package.  When I install the component on a Joomla 2.5 site, it installs with no errors.  Then, when I enable the plugin, I get two instances of the video inserted into the database.  When I disable the plugin I will get one instance of the video inserted into the database.  This is not what I am after.

Ideally, when the user installs the plugin, I would like it to automatically enable the plugin.  If the plugin is enabled, then the video will show up in the database.  If the plugin is disabled, then the video will be not show up in the database.  Here is the current `xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<install version="1.7" type="plugin" group="system">
<name>Add Outkast</name>
<author>My Name</author>
<creationDate>November 2013</creationDate>
<copyright>Copyright (C) 2013 All rights reserved.</copyright>
<license>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL</license>
<authorEmail>my@email.com</authorEmail>
<authorUrl>myURL.com</authorUrl>
<version>1.7</version>
<description>This Plugin adds Outkast's Video Hey Ya.</description>

<files>
    <filename plugin="outkastplugin">outkastplugin.php</filename>
</files>

</install>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, I went for a different approach with this. I did it using an SQL file which gets executed upon installation.

Here is what everything looks like:

**Structure:**

```
file - outkastplugin.xml
file - outkastplugin.php
folder - sql 
  >> file - install.mysql.utf8.sql
```

**outkastplugin.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="2.5" type="plugin" group="system" method="upgrade">
   <name>Add Outkast</name>
   <author>My Name</author>
   <creationDate>November 2013</creationDate>
   <copyright>Copyright (C) 2013 All rights reserved.</copyright>
   <license>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL</license>
   <authorEmail>my@email.com</authorEmail>
   <authorUrl>myURL.com</authorUrl>
   <version>1.7</version>
   <description>This Plugin adds Outkast's Video Hey Ya.</description>

   <files>
      <filename plugin="outkastplugin">outkastplugin.php</filename>
      <folder>sql</folder>
   </files>

   <install>
      <sql>
        <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/install.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
      </sql>
   </install>

</extension>
```

**outkastplugin.php:**

```
<?php

defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

jimport( 'joomla.plugin.plugin');
jimport( 'joomla.html.parameter');

class plgSystemOutkastplugin extends JPlugin
{

    function plgSystemOutkastplugin()
    {

    }        

}
?>
```

**install.mysql.utf8.sql:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__mycomponent_outkastvideos` (
        `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `link_youtube` varchar(255) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO `#__mycomponent_outkastvideos` (`title`, `link_youtube`) VALUES ('Outkast', 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/PWgvGjAhvIw?rel=0');
```

I have sent you the full zip package via e-mail.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hey Ya!  That worked great!  The only small problem I see is that every time I enable or disable the plugin in the extensions manager it is doubling the insert.  So on initial install there is one outkast, then after enabling there are two outkast rows.  Disabling again inserts 2 more with a total of 4?  Any idea why?

Comment: ahh ok. Do you want to insert the value into the database when the plugin is installed or after?

Comment: when it is installed is best (as it currently functions).  Is there a way to make it not double when enabled or disabled?

Comment: THanks for the update.  I have added the `<scriptfile>` call to my `xml` just below `description`.  I have emptied out the `outkastplugin.php` script and moved the code to `script.php` based on your update.  Now nothing happens at installation.  Could it be b/c I have removed the code from `outkastplugin.php`?

Comment: probably, leave what you had `outkastplugin.php` file as it was

Comment: well I tried leaving it as it was but that was causing the doubling of the entries.  I am going to keep making some changes, any other suggestions on how to adjust it?

Comment: I have noticed as well that when the plugin is enabled, everytime that I browse away from the view and then back to it there are 2 new duplicate entries being added.  It seems to me that I should have empty values in my `outkastplugin.php` file since the only action I want to take is hard coded into the `script.php` file.  Of course I've got to get the `script.php` file working first.

Comment: any idea on how to alter the script file?

Comment: just wanted to let you know that I have added a bounty to this one.  I know we are really close to a solution, so I added more info to the question.  Hope we can get this knocked out here within the next 5 days :)

Comment: @Presto -  yeah I noticed :) If you would like to send me the plugin via e-mail, I will be more than happy to test and come up with a solution as I find trial and error much easier. If you're happy with this then my e-mail is lodder15@hotmail.co.uk

Comment: THanks, just send a message.

Comment: @Presto - got the email, just testing now

Comment: thank you so much!  Now I see where I was missing the update with the install script. thanks!